# Stored function used in insert trough PHP runs multiple times

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to understand a strange behavior using PHP with mongodb 2.4.3 win32.
I try to have server side generated sequence ids.

When inserting documents using a stored function as one of the parameters it seems that the stored function is called several times at each insertion.

Let's say I have a counter initialized like this:

```
db.counters.insert( { _id: "uqid", seq: NumberLong(0) } );
```

I have a stored function named getUqid which is defined as

```
db.system.js.save( 
    { _id: "getUqid", 
      value: function () { 
                  var ret = db.counters.findAndModify(
                  { query: { _id: "uqid" }, 
                    update: { $inc: { seq: NumberLong(1) } }, 
                    new: true 
                  } );
                  return ret.seq; 
                  } 
             }  );
```

When I do three insertions like this:

```
$conn->test->ads->insert(['qid' => new MongoCode('getUqid()') , 'name' => "Sarah C."]);
```

I get something like that:

```
db.ads.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a34f8bf0774cac03000000"), "qid" : 17, "name" : "Sarah C." }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a34f8bf0774cac03000001"), "qid" : 20, "name" : "Michel D." }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51a34f8bf0774cac03000002"), "qid" : 23, "name" : "Robert U." }
```

Any clue why *qid* is getting stepped by 3 ? It should mean that I received three call to my stored function right ?

Thanks in advance for your help, Regards.

**PS:** secondary question: are NumberLong still required to be sure we have 64bit unsigned integer in internal mongodb storage ? Any command to cross-check that in the shell ?

Comment: First, Why don't you do findandmodify in PHP? Also you are probably getting this because you are evaling a functions while inserting it's result which is prolly causing some kind of double run action in MongoDB. Stored functions where never supposed to be used this way

Comment: Hi, 1) I'd like to insert in only one action, if possible of course. 2) I try to mimic this [create-an-auto-incrementing-field](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/), the "official" mongoDB proposal to do auto increment sequence id, but directly from PHP. Am I not understanding this correctly ?

Comment: No, the getNextSequence() is supposed to be a PHP function which then uses findandmodify. The JS is used because that is the shell language

Comment: In the example, the insert calls directly the getNextSequence right ? There is only one "call" to the DB to insert de document. Why can't we do that from PHP ?

Comment: There are two calls, one for findandmodify and one for insert, no you cannot do incrementing ids in one call, at least from what I can think off the top of my head

Answer (score 1):

Cross-referencing this question with [PHP-841](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-841). From the PHP side of things, you're actually storing a [BSON code value](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) in the `qid` field. You can likely verify that when fetching results back from the database or doing a database export with the `mongodump` command.

The issue is with the JS shell wrongfully evaluating the code type upon display, and that's the point where `findAndModify` is executed. This fix should be included in a subsequent server release.

In the meantime, Sammaye's suggestion to call `findAndModify` from PHP is the best option for this sort of functionality. Coincidentally, it is also what is done in Doctrine MongoDB ODM (see: [IncrementGenerator](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Id/IncrementGenerator.php)). It does require an additional round trip to the server, but that is necessary since MongoDB has no facility for executing JS callbacks during a write operation.

If minimizing the round-trips to MongoDB is of utmost importance, you could insert the documents by executing server-side JS through PHP with [MongoDB::execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.execute.php) and do something like returning the generated ID(s) as the command response. Of course, that's generally not advisable and JS evaluation has its own caveats.