# Auto-increment in MongoDB with CodeIgniter Alex Bilbie library

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb, auto-increment

First of all, sorry for my english and I'm beginning to study MongoDB. :)

I'm trying to insert a record using the CI library to MongoDB (https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library/tree/v2).

The insert works perfectly, but I can't insert using the recommended function to auto-increment **getNextSequence** (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/).

I tried the following ways without success.

**Controller:**

```
$data = array('_id' => 'getNextSequence("myid")', 
              'name' => 'Test '.time(),
              'email' => 'test@test.com');
$this->default_model->add($this->collection, $data);
```

**Model:**

```
function add($collection, $data){
    return $this->mongo_db->insert($collection, $data);
}
```

This returns the string '*getNextSequence("relatoriosid")*' as the "_id".

I also tried used the *command* function, like this:

**Controller:**

```
$query = 'db.collection.insert({_id: getNextSequence("myid"), name: "Test '.time().'"});';
$ret = $this->default_model->execute($query);
var_dump($ret);
```

**Model:**

```
function execute($query){
    return $this->mongo_db->command($query);
}
```

This way, returns the error:

```
["errmsg"]=> string(136) "exception: JavaScript execution failed: ReferenceError: getNextSequence is not defined near 'quence("myid"), name: "Teste 1374' "
["code"]=> int(16722)
["ok"]=> float(0)
```

Has anyone implemented something similar? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found a topic like my question answered by @jmikola that says it is not currently possible to perform a function during a write operation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17284555/704830

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented once mongoDB in one of my project.
I had faced similar problem. But one important thing i remember that we can not modify `_id`. Its `MongoDB` inbuilt properly. Neither its good to have the `auto-increament` in `MongoDB` because you need to implement that manually.

I will recommend that have another column in structure, you can call it anything, which will be virtual unique/primary key for you, lets say that column name is `data_id`.

```
$data = array('data_id' => md5(timestamp() . "<your string>"), 
              'name' => 'Test '.time(),
              'email' => 'test@test.com');
```

if we check the documentation, is specified that `Generally in MongoDB, you would not use an auto-increment pattern for the _id field, or any field, because it does not scale for databases with large numbers of documents. Typically the default value ObjectId is more ideal for the _id.` Here i am referring to [this link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/).

Even on the same link, its specified that `getNextSequence()` we need to write it. Its not inbuilt function.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: You're right about modify _id, but if I want to call some function in a insertion in a runtime with an auto-increment, isn't possible?

Comment: Ok.. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.max/ please check this link. As you said, we can modify the `_id`, start adding the integer values to `_id`. Each time before inserting, select the max(`_id`) record, increment it, and insert it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I got that problem too here is my solution.

Add this function to appflow\application\libraries

```
    public function getNextSequence($name = ""){
    if (empty($name))
    {
        show_error("In order to retrieve documents from MongoDB, a collection name must be passed", 500);
    }
    try{
        $collection_1 = 'counters';
        $collection = $this->db->{$collection_1};
    $result =  $collection->findAndModify(
        ['_id' => $name],
        ['$inc' => ['seq' => 1]],
        ['seq' => true],
        ['new' => true, 'upsert' => true]
    );
    if (isset($result['seq']))
    {
        return $result['seq'];
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

    }       
    catch (MongoCursorException $e)
    {
        if(isset($this->debug) == TRUE && $this->debug == TRUE)
        {
            show_error("MongoDB query failed: {$e->getMessage()}", 500);
        }
        else
        {
            show_error("MongoDB query failed.", 500);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the way to use.

```
$nextID = $this->mongo_db->getNextSequence("maindata_child");

$this->mongo_db->where(array('_id'=>$mongo_id))->push('maindata_child', array('id'=>$nextID,'data'=>$maindata_child))->update('main_data');
```

and don't forget to add collection "counters".

```
    db.counters.insert(
   {
      _id: "userid",
      seq: 0
   }
)
```

PS. I'm use this library https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Using-MongoDB-in-Codeigniter
Reference for solution : http://tbsmc.com/a/mwbwswmm-mongodb-how-to-insert-record-using-autoincrement-functionality.html